# Iterate through an array using each_with_index without a separate index variable

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to figure out how I can refactor my code below so that I can iterate through the array without using the "index1" and "index2" variables to keep track of my progress.

```
  board.each do |cell|
    diag1 << cell[index1]
    diag2 << cell[index2]
    index1 += 1
    index2 -= 1
  end
```

I tried using .each_with_index (see below), but I'm not sure how to increment my values for "i".

```
  board.each_with_index do |cell, i|
    diag1 << cell[i += 1]
    diag2 << cell[i -= 1]
  end
```

The array "board" is an n*n array of a tic-tac-to game that is at least 3x3 in size or larger and the block of code is supposed to check to see if there is a diagonal match. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Figured it out. Here is the working code snippet:

```
  board.each_with_index do |cell, i|
    diag1 << cell[i]
    diag2 << cell[-(i +1)]
  end
```

Comment: ... `i + 1` and `i - 1`? That will be broken, though, because you'll wrap around.

Comment: What is `board`, what is `cell` (shouldn't it be rather `row`)? What is the input (`board`) and what is an expected output?

Comment: An example of `board` might be `[["x", " ", " ", " "], [" ", "x", " ", " "], [" ", " ", "x", " "], [" ", " ", " ", "x"]]` with the expected output of `diag1` to be `xxxx`, which is passed through another part of the code to confirm that it's a win. Here is the complete working code I have now for reference.
https://gist.github.com/danielbonnell/6769fb41e2f5f4603fd9

Comment: I got the code working now. Someone just posted an answer that wasn't quite working right, but was close enough for me to figure out the rest. Here is a modification of what they posted.

  board.each_with_index do |cell, i|
    diag1 << cell[i]
    diag2 << cell[-(i +1)]
  end

Comment: Yeah, I did. But I wasnt happy with my answer so I removed it.

Comment: Are you aware that your current `check` method will return `true` for `OXXX`?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I used a different approach to the check method that solves this issue. Updated the gist if you're curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
diag1, diag2 = board.map.with_index {|row, i| [row[i],row[-i-1]]}.transpose
```

The main trick I'm using here is array's way of interpret negative argument. `array[-1]` always means the last element of an array, `array[-2]` denotes second last etc.

Comment: I like this even more.